# Place pocket(or design) on the cloth mesh

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I have a cloth pattern mesh.
The goal of my project is placing sensors on the cloth to detect signals from human.
So, I need to place sensor pockets on the cloth but only on the front part.

This is the pocket location. The sensor pocket should be square shape, but when I made it square, it became a hole on the mesh like the figure right. That`s why I will make this square opened(I will put very small gap at one of the corner)

[image]

[image]

Here, one problem occurs, that, when I simulate the cloth, the pocket line was disappeared.
I need to check if the sensor pocket locates well on its proper place.

[image]

This gif shows that when I simulate it, the pocket place was disappeared.
It can be any other solutions only if I can check the pocket place after I simulate.

PS I wanted to upload Blender file, but I do not know how to upload it. if you tell me, I will do that. (Since someone asked me to upload file before)

Comment: You can use Blend-Exchange (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload a file and edit the resulting link into your question.

Comment: can you add the hole after the simulation is over?

Comment: @Sanbaldo oh, thank you! I will try that!  For the second comment, i don't get it. What do you mean??

Comment: If you meant the hole in the picture, it was created from curve to mesh, and it was before I simulate. Since there is a hole, the cloth simulation was failed since even sewing line was sewed, the hole part was not shrink

Comment: Hi. The 'blender-internal-render-engine' tag relates to the Blender Internal render engine (present in blender 2.79 and removed in 2.8). (Also, as your question isn't about rendering, it wouldn't be relevant anyway :) - removed.)

Comment: In real life the pocket would be a separate piece of fabric stitched to the main garment. So create a new cloth item and pin it to the main suit using hooks. That way the deformation of the "vest" would drive the deformation of the pocket.

Comment: @susu thanks for your help :) yes, i know that, but what I want to do is that just  check if the pocket location is in proper location. That's it. So i want to do it simply. But your recommendation is really helpful. I will try it!